# is there way to do a console.log every few minutes on the background of the app with the example of the Expo task-manager?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, service, expo

I there a way to do a console.log every few minutes on the background of the app with the example of the Expo task-manager?
I try to do just a simple background task that works when the app is killed/after reboot 
just to make a console.log every few minutes with the example of the expo :

> [this is the example](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/task-manager/#example)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

const LOCATION_TASK_NAME = 'background-location-task';

export default class Component extends React.Component {
  onPress = async () => {
    const { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
    if (status === 'granted') {
      await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, {
        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Balanced,
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (

      <TouchableOpacity style={{textAlign: 'center',alignItems: 'center',justifyContent: 'center',paddingTop:200}} onPress={this.onPress}>
        <Text  >Enable background location</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

    );
  }
}

TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, ({ data, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    // Error occurred - check `error.message` for more details.
    console.log("error:", error);
    return;
  }
  if (data) {
    const { locations } = data;
    // do something with the locations captured in the background
    setInterval(function(){console.log(locations)}, 60)
  }
});
```

I just want simple console.log every few minutes to see that the task manager is really working.

Comment: I'm not familiar with React, but since the base is JS, can't you just initiate a `setInterval(function(){console.log(message)}, 60000)`

Comment: you need to use the location for use it ..can you show me a snack of your code change ?